# How to calculate Cumulated count of Id from two different temp tables using same source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift

My Table is like:

| ID | Type | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | activate | 01-11-2020 |
| 100 | Paid | 01-03-2021 |
| 100 | Paid | 01-06-2021 |
| 101 | activate | 01-03-2021 |
| 102 | activate | 01-04-2021 |
| 102 | paid | 01-04-2021 |
| 103 | activate | 01-04-2021 |
| 103 | paid | 01-06-2021 |

Now I have two temp tables:

```
   tbl1 as (
Select *,case when row_number() over(partition by id order by month)=1 then 1 else null End as Cont1 from table where type='activate'),
    
tbl2 as (select *,,case when row_number() over(partition by id order by month)=1 then 1 else null End as Cont2 from table where type='paid')
   
 select tbl1.id ,
    tbl1.type,
    tbl1.month as activate_month,
    tbl2.month as paid_month,
   -- datediff('month',tb1.month,tbl2.month) month_diff,
    Sum(Cont1) over (partition by 1 order by tbl1.month rows unbounded preceding) as distA,
    Sum(Cont2) over (partition by 1 order by tbl2.month rows unbounded preceding) as distP
    from tbl1 ta
    left join tbl2 tp on ta.id=tp.id
```

Scenario:
for type='activate' entry of id will exist only once but for type='paid' there might be multiple entries, so I want to count this id in cumulative order in such a way that we can consider the first entry in a count with a month.

Result I want:

| ID | Type | Amonth | Pmonth | countA | countp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | activate | 01-11-2020 | 01-03-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 101 | activate | 01-03-2021 | null | 2 | 0 |
| 102 | activate | 01-04-2021 | 01-04-2021 | 3 | 2 |
| 103 | activate | 01-04-2021 | 01-06-2021 | 4 | 3 |

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need 2 CTE's for this.
An aggregation of a self-join will be sufficient.

You see, the window functions *(f.e. row_number, dense_rank)* are processed after aggregation. So you can use them also on a `MIN`.

**For example:**

> ```
> select activate.id, activate.type
> , min(activate.month) as activate_month
> , min(paid.month) as activate_month
> , row_number() over (order by min(activate.month) asc) as rn_activate
> , case when min(paid.month) is not null
>   then row_number() over (order by min(paid.month) asc)
>   else 0 
>   end as rn_paid
> from yourtable as activate
> left join yourtable as paid
>   on paid.id = activate.id
>  and paid.type = 'paid'
> where activate.type = 'activate'
> group by activate.id, activate.type
> order by min(activate.month) asc;
> ```

| id | type | activate_month | activate_month | rn_activate | rn_paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | activate | 2020-11-01 | 2021-03-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 101 | activate | 2021-03-01 | *null* | 2 | 0 |
| 102 | activate | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-01 | 3 | 2 |
| 103 | activate | 2021-04-01 | 2021-06-01 | 4 | 3 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=bd81c1e6bc88d8df0051912fbe51efab)*

Comment: for redshift we need to modify this

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have access to a redshift. And there doesn't seem to exist a free online instance for redshift to test syntax. Is it that redshift requires explicite rows/range in the window functions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this can be done using analytic functions with `outer apply`.

```
Select Tbl.ID, Tbl.Type, Min(Tbl.[month]) As Amonth, Min(T.Pmonth) As Pmonth, 
       Count(Tbl.ID) Over (Order by Min(Tbl.[month]) Rows Unbounded Preceding) As countA, 
       Case When T.ID Is Not Null 
            Then Count(T.ID) Over (Order by Min(T.Pmonth) Rows Unbounded Preceding) 
            Else 0 
       End As countp
From Tbl Outer Apply (Select ID, Min([month]) As Pmonth 
                      From Tbl As T 
                      Where ID=Tbl.ID 
                            And Type='Paid' 
                      Group by ID) As T
Where Tbl.Type='activate'
Group by Tbl.ID, T.ID, Tbl.Type
Order by Min(Tbl.[month])
```

Data output:

| ID | Type | Amonth | Pmonth | countA | countp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | activate | 2020-11-01 | 2021-03-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 101 | activate | 2021-03-01 | NULL | 2 | 0 |
| 102 | activate | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-01 | 3 | 2 |
| 103 | activate | 2021-04-01 | 2021-06-01 | 4 | 3 |